# PHP Script running from command line but not in browser

Tags: browser, php

I am trying to get the Google Adwords API, and right out of the box there's an example directory that runs fine from the command line but it doesn't work properly when I go to in the browser it just reads:

Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
<?php
/**
 * This example gets keywords related to a seed keyword.
 *
 * Tags: TargetingIdeaService.get
 * Restriction: adwords-only
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * @package    GoogleApiAdsAdWords
 * @subpackage v201101
 * @category   WebServices
 * @copyright  2011, Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 * @license    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Apache License,
 *             Version 2.0
 * @author     Eric Koleda <api.ekoleda@gmail.com>
 */

error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);

// You can set the include path to src directory or reference
// AdWordsUser.php directly via require_once.
// $path = '/path/to/aw_api_php_lib/src';
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../src';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require_once 'Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsUser.php';
require_once 'Google/Api/Ads/Common/Util/MapUtils.php';

try {
  // Get AdWordsUser from credentials in "../auth.ini"
  // relative to the AdWordsUser.php file's directory.
  $user = new AdWordsUser();

  // Log SOAP XML request and response.
  $user->LogDefaults();

  // Get the TargetingIdeaService.
  $targetingIdeaService = $user->GetTargetingIdeaService('v201101');

  // Create seed keyword.
  $keyword = new Keyword();
  $keyword->text = 'mars cruise';
  $keyword->matchType = 'BROAD';

  // Create selector.
  $selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
  $selector->requestType = 'IDEAS';
  $selector->ideaType = 'KEYWORD';
  $selector->requestedAttributeTypes =
      array('CRITERION', 'AVERAGE_TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES');

  // Set selector paging (required for targeting idea service).
  $paging = new Paging();
  $paging->startIndex = 0;
  $paging->numberResults = 10;
  $selector->paging = $paging;

  // Create related to keyword search parameter.
  $relatedToKeywordSearchParameter = new RelatedToKeywordSearchParameter();
  $relatedToKeywordSearchParameter->keywords = array($keyword);

  // Create keyword match type search parameter to ensure unique results.
  $keywordMatchTypeSearchParameter = new KeywordMatchTypeSearchParameter();
  $keywordMatchTypeSearchParameter->keywordMatchTypes = array('BROAD');

  $selector->searchParameters =
      array($relatedToKeywordSearchParameter, $keywordMatchTypeSearchParameter);

  // Get related keywords.
  $page = $targetingIdeaService->get($selector);

  // Display related keywords.
  if (isset($page->entries)) {
    foreach ($page->entries as $targetingIdea) {
      $data = MapUtils::GetMap($targetingIdea->data);
      $keyword = $data['CRITERION']->value;
      $averageMonthlySearches =
          isset($data['AVERAGE_TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES']->value)
          ? $data['AVERAGE_TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES']->value : 0;
      printf("Keyword with text '%s', match type '%s', and average monthly "
          . "search volume '%s' was found.\n", $keyword->text,
          $keyword->matchType, $averageMonthlySearches);
    }
  } else {
    print "No related keywords were found.\n";
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print $e->getMessage();
}
```

What can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the script does whatever it's supposed to do, but simply doesn't send any data? Looking cursorily at the source code, that is possible

Comment: Does printf only print in the cli and not in the browser?

Comment: @Pete nope, printf always outputs, but there could be a scenario where  it never gets triggered. Try an unconditional `echo "OK"` to see what happens

Comment: echo "OK"; doesn't print unless I comment out $page = $targetingIdeaService->get($selector);

Comment: @Pete in that case it's likely that PHP crashes with an error message. Maybe `display_errors` is not turned on?

Comment: I've tried ini_set('display_errors',1); at the top of the script, but it still doesn't print anything

Comment: Something else strange is when I go to the page in Firefox it downloads and empty file (been trying in chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks sensible. Debugging PHP can be a pain, and there's often nothing better to do than add a load of `echo`s or `error_log`s and bisect your way through the code to find the line that's causing the problem. Whack in an echo at the top to make sure it's being parsed properly, and so on. The problem's either in the code, or the configuration, and you might have to resign yourself to some tinkering until you can get some more output from it.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the advice, I have found that this line is the cause of the problem (from commenting every thing out and working backwords:   $page = $targetingIdeaService->get($selector);

Comment: Are there docs for the API? Does the value of `$selector` look like the string that should be being passed in? Can you `print_r` the value of `$page` after the call, etc?

Comment: I actually just tried that, I print_r'd it and commented out the whole if / else after that, and it still doesn't print in the browser, when I try to run it in the cli again it actually prints out the whole response which contains multiple keywords from the adwords sandbox, the $selector appears exactly the same in browser and cli

Comment: This uses an "auth.ini" file to provide it credentials could that have an impact?